# All endpoints return 401/403 in ControllerTest when adding resourceserver in my Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

In these days, we are going to migrate our custom JWT filter to Auth0 IDP.

I was using Spring 2.7.1, WebFlux/Kotlin Coroutines in this project. I created [a sample project to demo Reactive Spring Security OAuth2 with Auth0 IDP issue](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/oauth2/api).

> BTW, I've maintained a WebMvc version to demo Spring Security OAuth2 and OAuth0(updated to Spring 2.7.1), in which [the tests are working well](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-security-auth0-sample/blob/master/api/src/test/java/com/example/demo/ApplicationTests.java).

When I added `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` to our project deps to enable OAuth2 resource server support in our backend API.

But now all API endpoints are protected and returns 401 or 403.

My security config like this.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun springWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity, reactiveJwtDecoder: ReactiveJwtDecoder): SecurityWebFilterChain =
http {

    csrf { disable() }
    httpBasic { disable() }
    formLogin { disable() }
    logout { disable() }

    // enable OAuth2 resource server support
    oauth2ResourceServer { jwt { jwtDecoder = reactiveJwtDecoder } }
    exceptionHandling {
        authenticationEntryPoint = problemSupport
        accessDeniedHandler = problemSupport
    }
    authorizeExchange {
        authorize(pathMatchers(GET, "/v1/me"), authenticated)
        authorize(anyExchange, permitAll)
    }
}
```

The testing codes is like this, check [the complete codes](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/oauth2/api/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.kt#L40-L57)(The tests are ported from other projects, I have not added jwt mock).

```kotlin
@Test
fun `get all posts`() = runTest {
    coEvery { posts.findAll() } returns flowOf(
        Post(
            id = UUID.randomUUID(),
            title = "test title",
            content = "test content"
        )
    )

    client.get()
        .uri("/posts").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk
        .expectBodyList(Post::class.java).hasSize(1)

    coVerify(exactly = 1) { posts.findAll() }
}
```

The `get all posts` endpoints is set to `permitAll`, when running `curl http://localhost:8080/posts` command in a opening Powershell, **it works well and print all posts in the console**.

When running test of `GET /posts` endpoint. I got the following info from console.

```bash
2022-07-01 12:45:27.021 DEBUG 14132 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [6144e499] HTTP GET /posts
2022-07-01 12:45:27.069 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [26193fe] HTTP GET "/posts"
2022-07-01 12:45:27.108 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-1] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@6fc32403
2022-07-01 12:45:27.110 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-1] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match
2022-07-01 12:45:27.146 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2022-07-01 12:45:27.151 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2022-07-01 12:45:27.151 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /posts' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2022-07-01 12:45:27.152 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2022-07-01 12:45:27.156 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/posts' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@66bdd968
2022-07-01 12:45:27.159 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@529dcf30'
2022-07-01 12:45:27.160 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied
2022-07-01 12:45:27.174 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@529dcf30'
2022-07-01 12:45:27.184 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [26193fe] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2022-07-01 12:45:27.189 DEBUG 14132 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [6144e499] [609b7bfb] Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2022-07-01 12:45:27.207 ERROR 14132 --- [           main] o.s.t.w.reactive.server.ExchangeResult   : Request details for assertion failure:

> GET /posts
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Accept: [application/json]

No content

< 401 UNAUTHORIZED Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: [Bearer]
< Cache-Control: [no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
< Pragma: [no-cache]
< Expires: [0]
< X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
< X-Frame-Options: [DENY]
< X-XSS-Protection: [1 ; mode=block]
< Referrer-Policy: [no-referrer]

0 bytes of content (unknown content-type).


java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<401 UNAUTHORIZED>
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :401 UNAUTHORIZED
<Click to see difference>
```

I have set logging level to `TRACE`, but there is no log to check our pathmatcher rules. **It seems it does not check the pathmatchers in the authorizeRequest.**

I have set `disabled` to `crsf`, but crsf filter still participate in the security check progress, it also tired to match the `/logout` url.

Comment: And your test looks like?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Updated the post, and create a simple example project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `WebFluxTest` annotated tests did not scan my custom `SecurityConfig`( **which is a simple config NOT extends the XXXSecurityConfigurerAdapater**) in the project, but use the Spring Boot built-in default security config instead.

Currently I have to add my `SecurityConfig` explicitly to enable it in the tests.

```kotlin
class TestsClass{

   @TestConfiguration
   @Import(SecuirtyConfig::class)
   class TestConfig

   //test methods
}
```

I am not sure it is the original design purpose or other reason.

Answer (score 1):

@WebfluxTest / @WebmvcTest load very little conf. I do import my web-security cong like you do in your answer.

You might whish to unit test the production security rules for the controller endpoint. If so, import regular security conf (not a permitAll() test conf) and configure security context with either:

- `jwt()` WebTestClient mutator / WebMvc post-processor from spring-security-test
- `@WithMockJwtAuth` from [spring-addons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)